# Problem connecting to SSRS reporting services

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, connectivity

When I try to connect to my reporting services server (SQL Server 2005) from my local machine, SQL Server 2014 I get the error message below

> Invalid Namespace (System.Management)

[image]

But when I RDP into my reporting services server and connect to reporting services there, everything is fine.

There is nothing wrong with the reporting services.

Is there a way to connect to SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services from a SSMS 2014?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem except my Reporting Service is 2008 R2.

Anyway I have SSMS 2014 on the server where Reporting Service is installed and get the same error.

I have installed SSMS 2008 R2 and straight away it works.

**So you must have same version SSMS as Reporting service.**

And here is [explanation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e06c2d43-d6e1-4132-91e3-65da6975df8d/ssms-2014-to-ssrs-2012-wmi-connection-error-invalid-namespace?forum=sqlreportingservices):

In Reporting Services, the namespace for SSRS 2014 is **root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\RS_\v12\Admin**
while the namespace for SSRS 2012 is
 **root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\RS_\v11\Admin**.